# Impact of reducing fertility rate of poor, high birth rate, agricultural country in Africa

Tags: development-economics, development, population-economics

In a poor, population-dense country in Africa with an economy based entirely on agriculture (like Burundi) and a high birth rate that is contributing to poverty due to existing food insecurity, what would be the impact of reducing the birth rate?

Would there be any downsides of bringing families down from an average fertility rate of 4-6 kids? Since most people depend on utilizing the children's labor to help in the fields, would a lower birth rate actually hurt the country's economy?

Comment: How do you recommend doing that? Fertility rate is more of an effect than a cause, isn't it?

Comment: @user253751 Legalizing certain forms of abortion, sexual education, handing out free condoms or for an extreme example China's one child policy...there are a variety of ways policy can impact fertility rates.

Comment: So, those things are all causes which have effects. This is an effect which could have more effects.